# How to perform pandas reindex in polars

Tags: python-polars

In pandas, I can `reindex()` the dataframe using multi-index to make the date range consistent for each group. Is there any way to produce the same result in polars?

See example below using pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({
             "date":pd.date_range("2022-01-01", "2022-06-01", freq="MS"),
             "group":["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"],
             "value":[10,20,30,40,50,60]
     }).set_index(["group", "date"])
new_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([data.index.levels[0].tolist(), data.index.levels[1].tolist()], names=["group", "date"])
data.reindex(new_index)
```

which transform data from:

```
                  value
group date             
A     2022-01-01     10
      2022-02-01     20
      2022-03-01     30
B     2022-04-01     40
      2022-05-01     50
      2022-06-01     60
```

to below where both groups are having the same date range:

```
                  value
group date             
A     2022-01-01   10.0
      2022-02-01   20.0
      2022-03-01   30.0
      2022-04-01    NaN
      2022-05-01    NaN
      2022-06-01    NaN
B     2022-01-01    NaN
      2022-02-01    NaN
      2022-03-01    NaN
      2022-04-01   40.0
      2022-05-01   50.0
      2022-06-01   60.0
```

Answer (score 1):

As you may have read, [polars does not use an index](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/coming_from_pandas.html).

In this case your `new_index` is a cross join of the unique values of your index columns which can easily be reproduced in polars.

```
pldata=pl.DataFrame({
            "date":pl.date_range(datetime(2022,1,1), datetime(2022,6,1),'1mo'),
            "group":["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"],
            "value":[10,20,30,40,50,60]
    })

pl_index = pldata.select(pl.col('date').unique()) \
        .join(
              pldata.select(pl.col('group').unique()), 
         how='cross'
         )
```

Then, instead of the reindex command, you do another join, this time an outer join  on those columns, with a sort to get back your order

```
pldata.join(plnew_index, on=['date','group'], how='outer').sort(['group','date'])
```

You can make a helper function for making the `plnew_index` for an arbitrary number of index cols

```
def make_plindex(df, indexcols):
    newdf=df.select(pl.col(indexcols[0]).unique())
    for curcol in indexcols[1:]:
        newdf=newdf.join(df.select(pl.col(curcol).unique()), how='cross')
    return newdf
```

and, of course, if you don't actually care about the intermediate df you can extend that function by putting the outer join in it returning the final result

```
def make_nullrows(df, indexcols):
    newdf=df.select(pl.col(indexcols[0]).unique())
    for curcol in indexcols[1:]:
        newdf=newdf.join(df.select(pl.col(curcol).unique()), how='cross')
    return df.join(newdf, on=indexcols, how='outer')
```

Then you can just do

```
make_nullrows(pldata, ['group','date'])
```